# Vue creating a plugin

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I feel a bit like I'm missing something very simple, but I've been trying different stuff out and searching all over the place and can't figure out how to use a method from a custom plugin in my Vue application.

In 'vuePlugin.js' I have something like:

```
const myPlugin = {};
myPlugin.install = function(Vue, options){
    Vue.myMethod = function(){
        console.log("It worked!");
    }
}
```

In my main.js I have:

```
import myPlugin from './js/vuePlugin.js'
Vue.use(myPlugin);
```

Then in my App.vue I have:

```
export default {
    name: 'app',
    props: {},
    data () {
        return{ someData: 'data' }
    },
    beforeCreate: function(){
        myMethod();
    }
}
```

With this I get an error that "myMethod is not defined".

I've tried saying:

```
var foo = myPlugin();
console.log(foo);
```

In my console I get an object called "install" with arguments:
"Exception: TypeError: 'caller' and 'arguments' are restricted function properties and cannot be accessed in this context. at Function.remoteFunction"

All of the documentation seems to just show how to create the plugin and "use" it, but not actually how to access anything in it.  What am I missing here?

Comment: I have no experience with vue but I fiddled a bit and calling `Vue.myMethod();` in `beforeCreate` works, so maybe try that. Also I was using just `new Vue`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to export your object to be used in vuejs as follows

**`file vuePlugin.js`**

```
const myPlugin = {}
myPlugin.install = function (Vue, options) {
  Vue.myMethod = function () {
    console.log('It worked!')
  }
  Vue.prototype.mySecondMethod = function () {
     console.log('My second Method ')
  }
}
export default myPlugin
```

while calling the method you cannot call  the method directly, you have to use as following code shown

**`file  App.vue`**

```
export default {
    name: 'app',
    props: {},
    data () {
        return{ someData: 'data' }
    },
    beforeCreate: function(){
        Vue.myMethod(); // call from Vue object , do not directly  call myMethod() 
        this.mySecondMethod() // if you used prototype based method creation in your plugin 
    }
}
```

hopes it will help you